# Disable loading of nested locale (I18n) folders in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-7

After upgrading from Rails 6 to Rails 7, there seems to be a not-yet-fully-documented change in how I18n loads the config files. In Rails 7, files in subfolders (`config/locales/<folder>/*` are loaded as well, whereas in Rails 6 they were not loaded.

The [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files) still states:

> The default locale loading mechanism in Rails does not load locale files in nested dictionaries

I was able to find [this post](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/07/20/rails-7-allows-nested-locales.html) where it states that Rails 7 *does* load nested folders (which is the behavior I see), as well as [this Rails PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41872) that is on subject.

I believe the piece of code responsible for this, is in [`rails/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb#L60):

```rb
paths.add "config/locales",      glob: "**/*.{rb,yml}"
```

I would like to revert to the old behavior, of only loading the files directly under the locales folder, or at least be able to blacklist some subfolders. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to modify the `config.i18n.load_path` in your config?

Comment: `config.i18n.load_path` is empty, when observed from `config/application.rb`, so no. I also prefer to avoid doing things that are not sanctioned by the documentation, to retain compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Since paths are keyed [by the string used when `add`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7036bc2b633463e8ce1011f32ec5eb87ce435d06/railties/lib/rails/paths.rb#L66-L68), and i18n railtie paths [are set in the `add_locales` initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7036bc2b633463e8ce1011f32ec5eb87ce435d06/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L597-L601), one workaround would be to force the old behavior by overwriting the path for `config/locales`, eg:

```
  initializer :avoid_nested_locale_directories, before: :add_locales do
    paths.add 'config/locales', glob: '*.yml'
  end
```